# How to make out Reverse triangle and pyramid in Ruby using for loop?

Tags: ruby, loops

I want to print triangle & pyramid `"*"` using for loop.

> can somebody help me on this?

Output like :

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

and

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

Answer (score 4):

> 1: Print triangle using While loop

```
n = 5
 while n >= 1
   puts "* " * n
   n = n - 1
 end

* * * * * 
* * * * 
* * * 
* * 
*
```

---

```
n = 1
while n <= 5
  puts ("* " * n).rjust(10)
  n += 1
end

        * 
      * * 
    * * * 
  * * * * 
* * * * *
```

---

> 2: Print pyramid using loop

```
n = 4 # Set number of rows
i = 1

1.upto(n) do

  print ' ' * n
  print '*' * (2 * i - 1)

  print "\n"

  n -= 1
  i += 1
end

    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
```

Answer (score 3):

```
5.downto(1).each{|n| puts ("*" * n).ljust(5)}
1.upto(5).each{|n| puts ("*" * n).rjust(5)}
```